# Redis client.get not working but client.set is working

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

```
async function getRepos(req, res, next) {
    try {
        console.log('Fetching Data...');

        const { username } = req.params;

        const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);

        const data = await response.json();

        const repos = data.public_repos;

        // Set data to Redis
        await client.setex(username, 3600, repos);

        res.send(setResponse(username, repos));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500);
    }
}

// Cache middleware
async function cache(req, res, next) {
    const { username } = req.params;
    console.log(username)
    await client.get(username, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (data !== null) {
            res.send(setResponse(username, data));
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
}
```

When this code executes the set function works(checked by using redis-cli).But the get function does not work when I send the request to the api.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the Redis client's promise API with the callback API. Don't set a callback if you want to use `await` and vice versa.

```
// Cache middleware
async function cache(req, res, next) {
  const {username} = req.params;
  console.log(username);
  const data = await client.get(username);
  if (data !== null) {
    res.send(setResponse(username, data));
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```